# Какой смысл от reuseIdentifier в таблицах?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Не совсем понимаю смысл reuseIdentifier в таблицах, объясните кто-нибудь подробно что это и зачем это? Из прочитанного я понял то, что это идентификатор типа nsstring, присваиваем ему identifier, который указываем у свойства ячейки в storyboard или xib, и он нужен для того, чтобы повторно не создавалась ячейка, типа по этому идентификатору она копируется, или как-то так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея примерно такая: если у вас в таблице, допустим 1000 ячеек, они, конечно же, все в памяти не хранятся. А хранится ровно то количество, которое вы видите на экране. Чтобы все это дело оптимизировать еще больше, и довести производительность таблицы до максимально возможного уровня используется механизм повторного использования существующих ячеек. То есть, если у вас на экране 5 ячеек и вы скроллите вниз, то когда первая ячейка пропадает с экрана она не удаляется из памяти, а, допустим, используется заново на месте 7й ячейки. Чтобы весь этот механизм работал вам надо объявить, что все ячейки (или некоторые) могут использоваться заново, объявив им общий `reuseIdentifier`.

Вот вам пример того, как это выглядит

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>

@end

@implementation ViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    table.dataSource = self;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // здесь система проверит, есть ли в памяти не используемые ячейки данного типа
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell"];

    if(cell == nil) {
        // если ячейки нет, то создать новую
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"testCell"];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"new cell";
    } else {
        // если ячейка есть, то изменить ее
        cell.textLabel.text = @"reused cell";
    }
    return cell;
}
```